# How to overlay plots in python with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlay

I'm using two related packages that generate plots I want to overlay for comparison. I call a method called plot_spectro from each package which plots to plt. Then I must do plt.legend() and plt.show() to see them. What happens is two plots with the same data ranges appear, but I would like to overlay (superimpose) them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s.plot_spectro(xaxis=x, yaxis=y)

plt.xlim(-6,2)
plt.ylim(-2.5,2.5)

o1.plot_spectro(xaxis=x, yaxis=y,  color='b')

plt.xlim(-6,2)
plt.ylim(-2.5,2.5)

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an axis instance and pass it to both the plots as shown below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

s.plot_spectro(xaxis=x, yaxis=y, ax=ax) # <--- pass ax=ax here
o1.plot_spectro(xaxis=x, yaxis=y,  color='b', ax=ax) # <--- pass ax=ax here

plt.xlim(-6,2)
plt.ylim(-2.5,2.5)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```